# Android update removed "change account" button on login screen

Tags: multi-user

After a Android Update on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S5e, the button allowing to choose the user-login (or Android account, I mean here "multi-user feature of Android") does not show anymore.

The button nevers shows up. (neither after reboot nor after changing user through user parameters, see under)

So to change user, you have to log on the last logged user, and then go in the parameter >user and choose the user you want.

My other Samsung tablet does not have this problem.

Android Version : 11;
One UI Version : 3.1 (that's the Samsung UI, I guess) ;
Google Play last update 1 aug 2021

Comment: You should give more details, e.g. on the used Android version and how the users were created, using the multiple user feature of Android or using some special app? Does the "change user" button never show up or only after a reboot?

Comment: I added the precisions you asked into the question. I really speak about the multiple user feature of android. and added the Android version

Answer (score 0):

I re-searched for an update. There was one availlable, installed it.
The "change user" button did not appear directly. But by changing the user once again throught the parameters, then it appear finaly on top right corner.

It's now working as expected.